# Python best practice: How to handle function parameters that can be 2 types?

Tags: python, pyspark

I am building a Python Class that works with PySpark dataframes or Hive tables. The input data can either be a `str` for table_name or a `DataFrame`. What is the Python best practice to do this? I wanted to do this so that it is flexible depending on the use case. The only difference is on how the data should be passed to the class (either as a table or a Spark DataFrame), everything else would be the same.

See example below:

```
class DataPipeline:

    def __init__(self, data):
        if isinstance(data, str):
            self.df = spark.read.table(data)
        elif isinstance(data, DataFrame):
            self.df = data
        else:
            raise ValueError("some error")

    def process_data(self):
       # do something with the self.df here
```

Comment: A good use of Python Docstrings, to tell the developers using your code what kind of input is expected.

Comment: Better yet, a type annotation(`data: str | DataPipeline` if you're on Python 3.10+, otherwise `data: typing.Union[str, DataPipeline]`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't. Make `__init__` expect a `DataFrame`, and make the caller responsible (perhaps via a class method) for converting a string to a `DataFrame` *before* `DataPipeline.__init__` is called.

```
class DataPipeline:

    def __init__(self, data: DataFrame):
        self.df = df


    @classmethod
    def from_string(cls, data: str):
        return cls(spark.read.table(data))


p1 = DataPipeline(some_data_frame)
p2 = DataPipeline.from_string("...")  # DataPipline(spark.read.table("..."))
```

---

[Ryan Singer](https://twitter.com/rjs) (supposedly; for as often as it is quoted, I've yet to find the original source) once said

> So much complexity in software comes from trying to make one thing do two things.

Here, you are trying to make one thing (`DataPipeline.__init__`) to two things (initialize a `DataPipeline` using a string, and initialize a `DataPipeline` with a `DataFrame`).

For the refactoring, I chose to make the simplest case (accepting a `DataFrame`) for `__init__`, with the more complex logic of first parsing a string into a `DataFrame` moved into a separate class method that calls `__init__` with an appropriate data frame.

---

(Whether you want to make any explicit runtime checks for type validation to fail early, or just assume that the caller will accept the consequences of failing to pass a value of the correct type, is up to you.)

Comment: How would this be used? `DataPipeline(df)` and then `DataPipeline.from_string('tablename')` ?

Comment: @heinistic `pipeline = DataPipeline.from_string(data_str)`.  The classmethod gets the class as the first param, and returns an instance (in this case), so you get an object back.  Also really do do this---makes reasoning about things much easier later, and prevents cluttering your inits with lots of typechecking.

Comment: Yes. The caller is ultimately responsible for knowing whether they already have a `str` or a `DataFrame`, and using the appropriate interface to create the `DataPipeline`, rather than making `DataPipeline` itself responsible for deciding what `data` is.

Comment: Just a comment on this: strs to be interpreted as tables and dfs are (in my book) very different types.  Sometimes it makes sense to accept multiple types---e.g. when writing stuff which handles paths, I'll normally do `Path()` on the input, so the fn/class handles anything which `Path` can turn into a path; I'll then declare it as `Path | str`.  This fits the use-case for path stuff quite nicely (somethings like `TemporaryDirectory` retun strs), and the types are not really *that* different to make it worth having a `from_str` method.

Comment: True; you can describe that, though, as simply "readvertising" `Path`'s ability to handle either `Path` or `str` arguments, rather than making any decisions of your own about how to handle values of different types.

Comment: In the case of `Path`, I would argue that `PurePath._parse_args` is making up for the lack of a `PathLike` protocol (which might allow a `__path__` method that returns a `PurePath` instance); then, `PurePath.__new__` could simply take a sequence of `PathLike` instances rather than having to check if each argument is either a `str` or a `PurePath` value.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right basic idea but the syntax is wrong -- use `raise` to raise an exception(I'd suggest `TypeError` for an invalid type rather than `ValueError`), and make sure you're setting `self.df` instead of the local var `df`:

```
class DataPipeline:

    def __init__(self, data):
        if isinstance(data, str):
            self.df = spark.read.table(data)
        elif isinstance(data, DataFrame):
            self.df = data
        else:
            raise TypeError("Data must be str or DataFrame")
```

Comment: Ah yes, I made these mistakes because I was rushing posting this question. Thank you!